# Cordova and Android: keyboard doesn´t appear when click on input tag

Tags: android, cordova

I use Cordova 2.9.0 and Android whit minimun api 10. I have the follow inputs:

```
<input class='inputSignup' id='name' type='text' placeholder='Nombre'>
<input class='inputSignup' id='lastname' type='text' placeholder='Apellidos'>
<input class='inputSignup' id='email' type='email' placeholder='Correo'>
<input class='inputSignup' id='pass' type='password' placeholder='Contraseña'>
<input class='inputSignup' id='pass1' type='password' placeholder='Repita su contraseña'>
<input id='sigup' type='button' value='Registrame'>
```

The problem is in the first input. If I click it don´t appear the keyboard, but If I  click on the others input the keyboard appear. I don´t understand this behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: are you using iscroll or any other javascript library?

Comment: I´m use jQuery, requirejs wiht textjs, backbonejs, bootstrapjs and underscore

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit config.xml file.

Change `<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />` value to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Additionally, the problem was that a `header`element hides the `input`. For this reason didn´t work it.